# How to assign an object retrieved from API REST to a singleton Class?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, singleton

I have a singleton object and i need assign the object returned by a API REST, and nothing is modified when I do it.

Singleton:

```
public class Stations {
   private static Stations instance = null;
   private List<Station> stations;
   private Stations() {
      // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
   }
   public static Stations getInstance() {
      if(instance == null) {
         instance = new Stations();
      }
      return instance;
   }
   public List<Station> getStations(){
       return this.stations;
   }
}
```

The Call:

```
public class StationsCall implements Job {
    private Stations stations = Stations.getInstance();
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {

        WebTarget targetGet = client.target("http://wservice.viabicing.cat/v2/stations");
        this.stations = targetGet.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).get(new GenericType<Stations>(){});
    }
    public List<Station> getStations(){
        List<Station> aux = this.stations.getStations();
        return aux;
    }
}
```

Comment: your are using `private Stations stations = new Stations();` here. This create an instance but not the same as the singleton instance. Use `Stations.getInstance()` instead

Comment: Sorry i edited the code right now and it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: `this.stations = targetGet.request...` will receive the singleton reference ? Seems you recreate a new `Stations` each time, which is strange having a private constructor...

Comment: I think that no...

Comment: What ? Ok what is the `targetGet` shoud do with the singleton ? Don't see any insertion of `Station` here so ther is always gonna be an empty list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `this.stations = targetGet.request(...)` only modify the field `stations` of the class `StationsCall`, it doesn't modify the actual singleton, you should not even be able to create an instance of `Stations` since its constructor is `private`.

What you need is a **setter** in your singleton to set the current list of stations.

Something like this:

```
public class Stations {
    // Use an AtomicReference to make sure that all threads see the last list of stations
    private final AtomicReference<List<Station>> stations = new AtomicReference<>();
    private Stations() {
        // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
    }
    public static Stations getInstance() {
        // Lazy create your instance of Stations using a static inner class
        // for thread safety
        return StationsHolder.INSTANCE;
    }
    public List<Station> getStations(){
        // Get the last list of stations from the AtomicReference
        return this.stations.get();
    }

    public void setStations(List<Station> stations) {
        // Set the new list of stations and make it unmodifiable for thread safety
        this.stations.set(Collections.unmodifiableList(stations));
    }

    private static class StationsHolder {
        private static final Stations INSTANCE = new Stations();
    }
}
```

**NB:** I improved your code to make it thread-safe as a singleton has good chance to be used by concurrent threads.

Then your class `StationsCall` would be:

```
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
    ...
    Stations.getInstance().setStations(targetGet.request(...));
}

public List<Station> getStations(){
    return Stations.getInstance().getStations();
}
```

---

Assuming that what you really need is the ability to get the current list of stations to only centralized its access and you don't care if it is a singleton or not, then your code should rather be:

```
public class Stations {
    // Use an AtomicReference to make sure that all threads see the last instance
    private static final AtomicReference<Stations> INSTANCE = 
        new AtomicReference<>(new Stations());
    private List<Station> stations;

    public Stations() {
    }

    public Stations(final List<Station> stations) {
        // Make a safe and unmodifiable copy of the list of stations
        this.stations = Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(stations));
    }

    public static Stations getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE.get();
    }

    public List<Station> getStations(){
        return this.stations;
    }

    public static void setInstance(Stations stations) {
        // Set the new instance
        INSTANCE.set(new Stations(stations.getStations()));
    }
}
```

Then your class `StationsCall` would be:

```
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
    ...
    Stations.setInstance(targetGet.request(...));
}

public List<Station> getStations(){
    return Stations.getInstance().getStations();
}
```

Comment: Much better ! But probably still a problem with this line `this.stations = targetGet.request...`

Comment: @AxelH yes indeed I assume here that `targetGet.request(...)` returns a `List` of `Station` but I don't believe that it is should be hard to do it, I simply here focus on the initial question which is *How to assign a object getted from API REST to a singleton Class?*

Comment: Because, even if it was not really safe, his code should work (or I missed something ?)

Comment: @AxelH it is no more a singleton if you can create a new instance and re-set it, so no his code cannot work, starting from the fact that `Stations` has a `private` constructor so it won't be possible to create an instance of `Stations` while parsing the JSON content, he must use a wrapper class just to get the list and apply what I propose here